# Error transmitting data using RESTful HTTP

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I need to transmit data from Java Servlet backend to frontend. The data is transmitted in JSON and that's the servlet I've written to implement it:

```
@WebServlet("/add")
public class AddElementServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter printWriter = resp.getWriter();
    printWriter.write("{\"id\":1,\"content\":\"Hello, World!\"}");
    printWriter.close();
}
}
```

The web-page on this address shows the string of JSON. At the same time, the front doesn't get the data transmitted. My guess is to use RequestDispatcher, but I see neither `.forward()` nor `.redirect()` method useful here.
That's the versions of the frontend that I used to receive data.
1st:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/add'
}).then(function(data) {
    alert('Data: '+ data + ' ' + data.id + ' ' + data.content);
    $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
    $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
});
});
```

2nd:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8081/add')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
}).then(function(json) {
console.log('parsed json', json)
}).catch(function(ex) {
console.log('parsing failed', ex)
})
```

Where is my mistake and how can I solve it?

Comment: When you access the frontend, any message in the browser console ?

Comment: Do you get any response with Postman?

Comment: @PeterMmm, in the 2nd case it shows only "parsed json".

Comment: @JanezKuhar, yes, I get exactly the same response that I expect.

Comment: I believe Postman has the option to generate JavaScript equivalent of your request. See: [Generating client code](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/)

Comment: I generated it and tried, but there is still an empty line in the console. I also tried different browsers, but the data still doesn't appear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: @JanezKuhar, no, they look similar, but are not about the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of CORS policy appeared, and I tried to solve it by adding `mode: 'no-cors'` to `fetch()`. But that didn't allow to transmit data for some reason - this way only a special extension to a browser may help. Search for it in extension markets of your browser developers' page.